# onScrolled RecyclerView not triggered after DataSet changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with an endless scroll (network requests) and a "query" functionality (filter items). At first, everything works great, when the list is close to the end it triggers the `onScrolled` method and consequently a network call is executed. The problem appears when I "clear" the entire collection used by the RecyclerView after making a "query" to the server. **In this case the `scrollListener` is no longer triggered**.

If the result of the network call is incremental (pagination) I do this:

```
public void updateList(List<Candidate> users) {
    final int positionStart = list.size() + 1;

    list.addAll(users);
    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, list.size());
}
```

If it's not an incremental result (new data) I do this:

```
public void refreshList(List<Candidate> users) {
    if (list.size() > 0) list.clear();


    list.addAll(users);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

For completeness, the implementation of the endless scroll I use is something like this: [gist](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)

I don't know if clearing the entire list is the problem... I've even thought I could just use `removeOnScrollListener()` before the collection is cleared and then add it back (`addOnScrollListener()`) but this doesn't same to work.

**What strategy should I take?**